# Why does vue-cli-service not find electron-builder while building the Flatpak?

Tags: flatpak, flatpak-builder

I am trying to Flatpak a Vuejs/Electron application. During build-time I can call Electron-Builder (but because it is a Vue application it complains about not finding `background.js`). The standard way of packaging Vuejs seems to be to use:

```
vue-cli-service electron:build
```

But calling that during build-time of the Flatpak shows this error:

**Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again**

Is there something that is missing for `vue-cli-service` to run correctly, that is not included in `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add this command to the `build-commands`:

```yaml
build-commands:
  # For some reason the install.js in the electron folder has to be executed
  - cd node_modules/electron && node install.js
  # After that you can run the electron:build
  - node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service electron:build
```